# SystemInfo как улучшить код?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Проблема в том что выходит слишком много foreach, как всё это можно сократить?

```
private static string pcCPU;
private static string pcGPU;
private static string pcLocalIP;
private static string pcExternalIP;
private static string pcAntivirus;

string savePath = @"C:\Sys.txt";
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Append))
{
    using (StreamWriter twf = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        foreach (ManagementBaseObject avResult in avsearcher.Get())
        {
            pcAntivirus = "& " + (avResult.GetPropertyValue("displayName")).ToString();
            pcAntivirus = (pcAntivirus.StartsWith("& ")) ? 
                                pcAntivirus.Substring(1) : 
                                pcAntivirus;
            twf.WriteLine(" антивирус: " + pcAntivirus);
         }
         foreach (ManagementObject gr in gs.Get())
         {
             foreach (PropertyData pty in gr.Properties)
             {
                 if (pty.Name == "Description")
                 {
                     pcGPU += pty.Value.ToString();
                     twf.WriteLine("  Видеоадаптер: " + pcGPU);
                 }
             }                 
         }
         foreach (ManagementObject gob in sar.Get())
         {
             twf.WriteLine("  Модель компьютера: " + gob["Manufacturer"] + gob["Model"]);
         }
    }
}
```

P.S:
Я вот попробовал так сделать, но тут не получается:

1 - Выводит ошибку Invalid Class

2 - в twf нельзя записать WriteALLtext, можно только Write

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (ManagementBaseObject avResult in avsearcher.Get())
{
Sb.Append(" антивирус: ").Append(pcAntivirus).Append("\n");
}
foreach (ManagementObject gr in gs.Get())
{
foreach (PropertyData pty in gr.Properties)
{
if (pty.Name == "Description")
{
Sb.Append("  Видеоадаптер: ").Append(pcGPU).Append(pty.Value.ToString()).Append("\n");;
}
}
}
foreach (ManagementObject gob in sar.Get())
{
Sb.Append("  Модель компьютера: ").Append(gob["Manufacturer"]).Append(gob["Model"]).Append("\n");;
}
twf.Write(sb.ToString());
```

А вот ошибка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На просторах интернета нашёл интересный код: с использованием List

[Информация о системе](http://vscode.ru/prog-lessons/get-comp-info-wmi.html)

Comment: У вас точно выставлено AnyCPU в свойствах проекта? А какая система (32- или 64-битная)?

Comment: Если у вас таки AnyCPU, посмотрите ещё сюда: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2014/08/11/wmi-missing-or-failing-wmi-providers-or-invalid-wmi-class/

Comment: @VladD, А лучше будет если использовать List<string> ??

Comment: Вы имеете в виду ваш код или ной ответ? В вашем коде непонятно, куда этот самый `List<string>` приткнуть. В моём я именно им и пользуюсь.

Comment: А в ином коде как записать всё в файл?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, вы можете отделить получение данных от их вывода.

```
// зачем вам странный трюк с "& "?
var avNames = avsearcher.Get()
        .Cast<ManagementObject>()
        .Select(av => (string)av["displayName"])
        .ToList();

var graphicCardList = gs.Get()
        .Cast<ManagementObject>()
        .Select(mo => (string)mo["Description"])
        .ToList();

var computerInfoList = sar.Get()
        .Cast<ManagementObject>()
        .Select(gob => (string)gob["Manufacturer"] + gob["Model"])
        .ToList();
```

И теперь запись:

```
File.AppendAllLines(
        savePath,
        avNames.Select(s => $"  Антивирус: {s}"),
        Encoding.UTF8);

File.AppendAllLines(
        savePath,
        graphicCardList.Select(s => $"  Видеоадаптер: {s}"),
        Encoding.UTF8);

File.AppendAllLines(
        savePath,
        computerInfoList.Select(s => $"  Модель компьютера: {s}"),
        Encoding.UTF8);
```

Циклы не нужны вовсе.

Comment: ладно флуд удаляю, а по делу, думаю стоит дополнить, что WMI умеет возвращать только коллекции, так что либо явные циклы, либо LiNQ.

Comment: Спасибо за пример на LinQ возьму на вооружение, вот только с циклами у меня не получается,нижний пост!

Comment: @ArteS: А какой текст исключения? (И лучше либо дополнить вопрос (там есть ссылка «править»), либо задать отдельным вопросом.)

Comment: @VladD, А можно Ваш способ с LINQ занести в `stringbuilder` и затем сделать всё записать в файл, просто чтобы не писать каждый раз `File.AppendAllText(...);`

Comment: @ArteS: Проще всего добавить `Concat`: `avNames.Select(s => $"  Антивирус: {s}").Concat(graphicCardList.Select(s => $"  Видеоадаптер: {s}")).Concat(computerInfoList.Select(s => $"  Модель компьютера: {s}"))`, и всё это один раз записать в файл.

Comment: @ArteS: `File.AppendAllLines(path, вот-это-длинное-выражение, Encoding.UTF8)` (`Lines`, а не `Text`!)

Comment: @ArteS: И в ответе тоже, да

Comment: @VladD,спасибо) очень полезная информация с linq гораздо легче.

Comment: @ArteS: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!

Comment: @VladD, Можете мне помочь разобраться в [Чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26962/c-net--)

Answer (score 0):

сократить вряд ли, а улучшить - разбить на методы отдельные логические участки.
Текст собирать в `StringBuilder` и по завершению запись в файл.

Invalid Class - платформа х86 стоит? смените на `AnyCPU`.
Не стоит все брать в `using`, он нужен для сохранения в файл, когда дойдет до сохранения, там стрим и создать и записать.
В `sb.ToString()` как раз и будет весь текст, он write-ом и запишется

Comment: AnuCPU стоит,  если using убрать то весь код у меня ошибки выдает ( Если (StreamWriter (savePath) стоит!, Можете помочь как это будет выглядеть?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что строка с using полностью не нужна в том месте и обрамление всего кода в скобки соответственно. Запись в файл делайте когда все данные будут собраны тем же File.AppendAllText(savePath, sb.ToString)